Logic for calculating fees in UniswapV3
In the computeSwapStep function, can feeAmount = uint256(amountRemaining) - amountIn exceed amount * fee / (1e6 - fee) in the case where sqrtRatioTargetX96 is not reached?
    function computeSwapStep(
    ...
            // cap the output amount to not exceed the remaining output amount
            if (!exactIn && amountOut > uint256(-amountRemaining)) {
                amountOut = uint256(-amountRemaining);
            }

            if (exactIn && sqrtRatioNextX96 != sqrtRatioTargetX96) {
                // we didn't reach the target, so take the remainder of the maximum input as fee
                feeAmount = uint256(amountRemaining) - amountIn; <-
            } else {
                feeAmount = FullMath.mulDivRoundingUp( <-
                    amountIn,
                    feePips,
                    1e6 - feePips
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

